# Solving an Integral - $ \int t^2\frac{\left(2t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c} \right )^{2k}}{(at^2+bt+c)} \ dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do we solve $ \int t^2\frac{\left(2t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c} \right )^{2k}}{(at^2+bt+c)} \ dt \tag 1 $ to a finite form?

1. $k,a,b,c$ are constants
2. $at^2+bt+c$ does not guarantee equal roots always

Comment: Always write what you have tried so far- you can factorize the bottom into roots in the form of $a_1+b_1i$ and $a_1-b_1i$ for some $a_1$ and $b_1$ and maybe use partial fractions, I haven't tried. And your numerator simplifies into $(2t)^{2k}\times (at^2+bt+c)^k$

Comment: If I have nt tried why would I put second condition? Is that your reason for downgrading my question?

Comment: Yes it was me who downvoted your question, I like the question itself but I don't like any question that just poses a problem and doesn't put any thought into it

Comment: Ping me if you edit your question to  show what you've tried- it IS an interesting question after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a CAS, there is a closed form expression $$I_k=\int t^2\frac{\left(2t\sqrt{at^2+bt+c} \right )^{2k}}{(at^2+bt+c)} \ dt $$ but it involves the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables which I do not suppose that this will be of major interest to you.

For  integer values of  power $k$, what you could easily show is that $$I_k=t^{2k+3}P_{2k-2}(t)$$ where $P_m(t)$ is a polynomial of $t$ of degree $m$. The expressions can be obtained using the binomial theorem.